# Executing a python script when system starts

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm developing a code that I wish to call everytime the system starts

I have a shell script that executes a "main.py" file, starting everything.

I've tried the following:
(The start script is called "start_organizer")

```
$ sudo cp start_organizer /etc/init.d
$ sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/start_organizer defaults
```

and I recive the following output:

```
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/start_organizer
```

Anyone can help me fix that?
I would appreciete other approaches on how to make a python script be called everytime the system is booted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

Based on this guide:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

update-rc.d  updates  the  System V style init script links /etc/rcrunlevel.d/NNname whosetarget is the script /etc/init.d/name.

That means in your command, you have to skip: /etc/init./d part:

So, following should work:

```
sudo update-rc.d start_organizer defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake here: `sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/start_organizer defaults`
If you check the man page for update-rc.d, you'll see that the parameter is not "path", but "name". The target is only searched in the `/etc/init.d` location, so your command should be:
`sudo update-rc.d start_organizer defaults`.